# Custom View with Url Links

Tags: android, listview

Below image is my View example. Array of text piece is retrieved from the server which consist of URL's (may be two URL's in a single piece). I need to present it as a list of items with scrolling. When user click the link, a web view comes to screen (typically a dialog screen).

With this scenario, am confused with these two options:

1) List view (Don't know whether links works perfectly)

2) A text view within a scroll view (Don't know how do i append all the text pieces and the divider)

Which option is better to go with? If you have better solution, please let me know.

Thanks
Aswin

[image: view example]

Comment: listview is always better in these type of situations.

Answer (score 0):

A listview would do well. For the links you can set the TextView to have an onClickListener() when defining the ListView adapter.